# How to pass the preferred hard disk size to "aws ec2 run-instances" command?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud

Here's the command I've been using so far:

```
aws ec2 run-instances --user-data file://user-data.sh --region us-east-1 --image-id ami-e13739f6 --key-name redacted1 --instance-type t2.small --query 'Instances[].InstanceId' --output text
```

Comment: The minimum instance snapshot size is for EBS instance like t2 is 8GB, you cannot specify smaller disk space.

Answer (score 0):

From the [`run-instances` documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/run-instances.html):

> `--block-device-mappings (list)`
>
> VirtualName=string,DeviceName=string,Ebs={SnapshotId=string,VolumeSize=integer,DeleteOnTermination=boolean,VolumeType=string,Iops=integer,Encrypted=boolean},NoDevice=string ...

It appears that `VolumeSize` is the parameter to use.